# i18n in Next.js with domain routing

Tags: next.js, next.js13, i18next

I need to make 1 next.js application, that will serve 2 languages and 2+ plus domains. The i18n with [Domain Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#domain-routing) looks great, but I can't find examples for local development.

So, I looked for a documented solution and found [Multi-Zone](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-zones). Is this a good solution for the Next 13 appFolder?

This should work on Netlify and later on Vercel.